# Is it safe to drive in the Baltic countries during winter?

Tags: driving, road-trips, winter, lithuania, riga

I am planning to drive from Kaunas to Riga between Christmas and New Years Eve. I would like to know how the road conditions usually are in this time of the year? Especially on the smaller roads. And is there anything special to consider when driving this route?

Comment: How safe it is would also depend on how experienced you are with driving in snowy/icy conditions